# Pandas - Remove first occurrence of value if it matches certain condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking to remove END from 'Task' column if there is no START before it. The data can be grouped by 'Session' and if the first occurance of the 'Task' is END, then I want to replace that specific occurrence with nAn value.

|  | Session | Task |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |  |
| 1 | 1 | END |
| 2 | 1 |  |
| 3 | 1 | START |
| 4 | 1 |  |
| 5 | 1 | END |
| 6 | 2 |  |
| 7 | 2 | START |
| 8 | 2 |  |
| 9 | 2 | END |
| 10 | 2 |  |
| 11 | 2 |  |
| 12 | 3 |  |
| 13 | 3 | START |
| 14 | 3 |  |
| 15 | 3 |  |
| 16 | 4 |  |
| 17 | 4 | START |
| 18 | 4 |  |
| 18 | 4 |  |
| 18 | 4 | END |

the DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Session':[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4],
         'Task':['', 'END', '', 'START', '', 'END', '', 'START', '', 'END', '', '', '', 'START', '', '', '', 'START', '', '', 'END']}
​
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

My initial thought was to get the first occurrence of 'Task' for each group, in a different data frame df2, and filter only rows with 'END' value, and then use index of df2 to remove the value from the original df.

Below is the expected table

|  | Session | Task |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 |  |
| 1 | 1 |  |
| 2 | 1 |  |
| 3 | 1 | START |
| 4 | 1 |  |
| 5 | 1 | END |
| 6 | 2 |  |
| 7 | 2 | START |
| 8 | 2 |  |
| 9 | 2 | END |
| 10 | 2 |  |
| 11 | 2 |  |
| 12 | 3 |  |
| 13 | 3 | START |
| 14 | 3 |  |
| 15 | 3 |  |
| 16 | 4 |  |
| 17 | 4 | START |
| 18 | 4 |  |
| 18 | 4 |  |
| 18 | 4 | END |

Comment: Do you mean if the first previous value is not START, or only if there is no START at all previously?

Answer (score 1):

Using Dataframe apply with a custom function to remove unmatched "END"

**Code**

```
def remove_unmatched(x):
    ' removes "END" value when not preceeded by "START" '
    preceeded = False
    result = []
    for z in x:
        if z == "START":
            preceeded = True                       # Set preceeded to True since found a start
            result.append(z)
        elif z == "END":
            result.append(z if preceeded else "")  # "END" or "" based upon whether preceede by "START"
            preceeded = False
        else:
            result.append(z)                       # value lunchanged
            
    return pd.Series(result, index = x.index)  # new series

df['Task'] = df.groupby('Session')['Task'].apply(remove_unmatched) # provides desired df
```

Comment: @ DarrylG thanks for the reply, however, I want to achieve this without using for loop

Comment: @ImSean007 sounds good.  Let's see if such an answer comes up.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

idx = df.where(df.groupby('Session').first().eq('END'))['Task'] == 'END'
df.loc[idx, 'Task'] = np.nan
```

#### How does it work?

Basically, you group per session and take the first non `NaN` value which is equal to `END`. That is, that session starts with an `END`. Then select all rows in the dataframe that matches that, for the `Task` column. It's necessary to add `== 'END'` such that there's a boolean column for indexing.

Then you can just locate those cases in the `Task column` and assign `NaN` to them.